# Server disconnected during configuration, now can't try configuration again

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-access

I was installing the DirectAccess role on a new server, and was partially through the Getting Started wizard (the end, where it was actually applying all the settings), and the target server got disconnected from the network in the middle of the procedure.

Of course, this broke EVERYTHING, to the point that the rollback portion failed (or something), and attempting to go through the Getting Started Wizard fails (because cmdlet unexpected something), and opening the Remote Access console does this:
[image: Pending Rollback]

This is what happens if I try to do the wizard again:

[image: cmdlet failed]

If I run the generated powershell script, this is what I get:

[image: initializing accounting]

So... Something to do with accounting failed? :/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by my using the Server 2012 management console to set up DirectAccess on a 2016 server. (facepalm)

Once I installed the console on the target server and did the setup from there, it at least finished configuration (though it's still not working properly according to the console).

Word to the wise: Use the same tools to configure products on the same version...